# Some garbage value is printing in the output. What is the reason?

Tags: c, output

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *getString()
{
    char str[]="textprint";
}  

int main()
{
    printf("%c",getString());    
    return 0;
}
```

What is the reason for receiving this garbage value in the output?

Comment: 1) `getString` does not return a value. 2) `%c` of `printf` requires `int`, not `char*`.

Comment: The function getString says it will return a char* but you aren't actually returning anything. Your compiler should have issued at least a warning. In addition, when returning a char*, you need to make sure that the pointer points to a string that is not on the stack, or else the data it points to will immediately become invalid as soon as the function returns.

Comment: @mgarey *you need to make sure that the pointer points to a string that is not on the stack*, I think the better way to phrase would be - the pointer points to a string that is still in scope (or is not local to the called function). C standard doesn't have the notion of a stack.

Comment: @mgarey  
understood the concept.Suppose if we are trying to print then we need to store in a character array right.

Comment: There are a lot of very fundamental errors in this short program. I would suggest reading a C programming book to pick up the basics. _Do not_ read that awful tutorialspoint website, it is trash.

Answer (score 3):

- compiling your code with `gcc -Wall` gets you several warnings
- fixing them (making "version 1") gets you the warning which would have told you the core problem of your code
- fixing the last warning (making version 2) gets you working and safe code
- I added an alternative, to print what you probably wanted to print
- I added a guess on what the purpose of your function is
  (it didn't convince me without guessing)
- I added a safety precaution, which prevents some of the easier-to-make errors with string which are statically defined arrays of char

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// version 2
// this is a change done after all other warnings were resolved,
// if you try it yourself, keep the version 1 (see below) to see the
// enlightening warning
char str[]="textprint";

// example for "localisation" strings
char strFr[] = "imprimertexte";


const char *getString(void) // better signature
// (with void as parameter list) for function, for good practice;
// the keyword "const" prevents changing the global string,
// which is a safety precaution
{
    // version 1 char str[]="textprint";
    // this version 1, after all the other warnings are resolved,
    // gets the enlightening warning 
    // "function returns address of local variable",
    // so this got moved somewhere else for version 2

    // Returning a pointer to a global variable/text from a function
    // is not obviously useful - at first glance.
    // One reason could be the design to be able to return different
    // pointers to different strings, depending on some condition.
    // I can imagine for example localisation of the texts.
    // That could look like 
    // if(localisation == English) {return str;}
    // else {return strFr;}

    return str; // to avoid warnings
    // a) "unused variable"
    // b) "control reaches end of non-void function"
}  

int main(void) // better signature for main, good practice
{
    printf("%c",*getString()); // change what to print, in order to avoid warning
    // "format '%c' expects type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'char *' " ,
    // by changing from "pointer to char" to 
    // "what a pointer to char points to", i.e. "char"

    printf("\n"); // print a newline for better readable output

    // Alternative, for printing the complete text:
    printf("%s\n", getString());

    // this attempts to change the global string
    // with the "const" keyword at the function head this does not work
    // it gets: "error: assignment of read-only location '*getString()'"
    // *getString()='T';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I thought of using "const" at the definition of the arrays, too. But with skipping that, the changes to get the first volley of warnings solved are more prominent and clear.

Comment: Appreciate the effort but I highly doubt the author is going to go through all the comments you wrote.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Without contradicting you, I optimistically hope OP will read them.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * getString(void)
{
    const * str = "textprint test";
    return str;
}  

int main()
{
    printf("%s\n", getString() );    
    return 0;
}
```

See demo [here](http://codepad.org/wpBeXmDr)

I ran this snippet fine at codepad.org without the const keyword but according to this [article](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/whats-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c/) it might be necessary to avoid a warning from the compiler.

The code creates a string literal which is stored in a read only location in memory and the pointer holds its address. When getString() executes, its return value is a pointer to that string literal.

According to the aforementioned [article](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/whats-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c/):

> "The C and C++ standards say that string literals have static storage"

This suggests that the code of the OP is redeemable, modified as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * getString(void)
{
    static char str[] = "textprint";
    return str;
}  

int main()
{
    printf("\n%s",getString());    
    return 0;
}
```

See demo [here](http://codepad.org/j1BKWW5F)

In this example, what gets created is an array such that each element  contains a character comprising the string.  The array would only exist within the scope of getString() except for the addition of keyword "static" which greatly extends the life of that array. As a result, when getString() executes in main() the return value is an address that points to the array kept intact in memory.

Note, getString() must contain a return statement in order for the funciton to evaluate as an argument for printf().  Also, without specifying  the keyword **static**, the address would point to corrupt memory and hence the resulting garbage data.

Comment: It might also be worth while to add why `char * str` is different from `char str[]` because the author might over look it and just add the return statement.

Comment: Does the output depend the editor.Because while running same program in online code editor  no value is being printed.The link is here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMMkNXaWNvUjFvNFE

Comment: It's not the editor but the development environment there which you need to figure out how to use to compile and execute C code.  Good luck.

Comment: @manjunathhiremath in the online editor you mentioned, all you had to do was press compile and press execute.

Comment: @manjunathhiremath: I tried just now "Term 1" at  tutorialspoint.com and manually did the compile, chmod and executed the code.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to add a return statement.
`return str;`

Comment: Its not the only problem but it is a problem and I'm glad this was pointed out as it should be.